# Add legend, north arrow, and scale bars

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, legend

I have three DEM layers on QGIS. They show slope, aspect and coloured DEM. I need to add a legend, north arrow, and scale bars to them but I'm completely confused at how to do this. The data I am using for these maps was given on a zip file so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to know anything about the information needed to add these details.

Comment: Have you looked at the QGIS documentation on [using the print layout](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it directly on the map canvas, without opening a print layout, with a result similar to  the image (customizable), you have to open the view -> decorations menu. After you can export the map to image.
[image]